# Checking whether two rasters intersect using R?

Tags: raster, r, intersection, rgeos

I would like a method for checking whether two rasters (or a raster and an extent) overlap that returns a Boolean and doesn't involve an if/then statement. Something like the `gIntersects` function. Here's my current approach:

```
#load libraries
library('raster')
library('rgeos')

#extent rectangle
rect <- extent(956328.8, 1036613, 825238.9, 936911.5)

# build blank raster
r <- raster(xmn=1035792, xmx= 1116792, ymn=825303.6, ymx=937803.6, resolution = 100)
r <- setValues(r, 0)

#check whether raster overlaps extent
r.crop <- crop(r, extent(rect))
if(is.null(r.crop)) {
    print('no overlap')
}else{
    print('overlap')
}
```

Comment: How are you timing the current performance? What data gives what time to process?

Comment: I'm less interested in performance and more in using fewer lines of code.

Comment: Then, as always, what you ask should match what you want - thanks for editing your question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
intersect(extent(r), rect)

intersect(extent(r), rect-10000)
```

`is.null` test will differentiate them  - note that you can add offsets to extents to grow/shrink them, and you can operate with extents, often there's no need to work with the data itself.

Comment: +1. Darn it, that's better.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a boolean result, use an error handler that returns true if the operation works, false if not:

```
tryCatch(!is.null(crop(r,extent(rect))), error=function(e) return(FALSE))
```

- `tryCatch`: try to evaluate and return the value of the first expression, and give the error message from the second if it doesn't work;
- `!is.null(crop(r,extent(rect)))`: returns  TRUE if an object is produced by the crop operation;
- `error=function(e) return(FALSE)`: returns FALSE if `crop` gives an error.

Comment: +1 for pointing out to a more general approach with `tryCatch` that helped me in another context.